# Не обновляется SSL-сертификат (висит просроченный при доступе к сайту)

Tags: nginx, ssl

Здравствуйте. На моем ресурсе используется nginx в качестве фронтэнда. Также используется SSL-шифрование. Когда подошел к концу срок действия сертификата, я заказал его перевыпуск, получил новый сертификат, поставил его, перезагрузил конфиг (/etc/init.d/nginx reload), перезагрузил сам nginx, но при попытке зайти на сайт сертификат все еще виден старый. Что я упустил? :)

Comment: Сделайте restart.

Comment: Не плохо, просто уведомления не приходят.

Возьми браузер, в котором не заходил на сайт, и посмотри, какой ему прийдёт сертификат.

-

Полностью останови nginx и запусти его снова.

Внимательно прогрепай все конфиги.

Переименуй файл с сертификатом, поправь конфиги и перезапусти с остановом.

Если за nginx у тебя стоит еще что-то вроде апача, посмотри, не отдаёт ли он сертификат.

Если это не поможет, напиши в nginx-овский maillist.

Comment: Может, все работает, как надо, а дело в сертификате?

Comment: Ответ на свой вопрос нашел здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14136279/renewal-expired-ssl-certificate-not-being-loaded-nginx
Проблема заключалась в том, что сертификат отдавал сервис CloudFlare, который мы используем для защиты от DDOS-атак. Авторизовался там, загрузил новые файлы ключа и сертификата. Почистил кэш браузера. Все, новый сертификат работает.